# phpMyAdmin - Database values changing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a table with two columns in phpMyAdmin and I set the first column as a primary key. 
Let's say that we have stored some data in the table. For example:

```
Column A Column B
    x1       y1
    x2       y2
    x3       y3
```

If I try to send some data like (x1, y4), will y1 be set to y4?
If not is there a setting to do it from phpMyAdmin? 
Or Do I need to use UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UPDATE` or `INSERT ON ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

MORE INFO @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks, I used on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

trying to insert a row with an existing primary key will cause an error, and that's exactly why no one uses things that might be duplicated as primary keys, to change the value of the existing row, you must use UPDATE, there is no other solution, but if you want to insert a new row, my advice is to go main stream, either use an autoincremented id as primary key, or use things like GUID(windows only).